# Proper way to pipe buffers in Node JS

Tags: node.js, stream, filesystems, pipe, fs

Take a look:

```
var Client = require('ftp');
var fs = require('fs');

var c = new Client();
c.on('ready', function() {
  c.get('foo.txt', function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;
    stream.once('close', function() { c.end(); });
    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('foo.local-copy.txt'));
  });
});
// connect to localhost:21 as anonymous
c.connect();
```

This piece of code is from https://www.npmjs.org/package/ftp. Basically it opens a read stream and pipes it into a write stream. At the end It closes the connection from the source.

Does the pipe method close the target stream after the piped stream (source) is closed? I couldn't find it on the API Documentation.

I made some test that from witch I can conclude it does it but I am no sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The destination stream is closed when the source emits an `end` event. This is documented in [Stream.pipe](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options):

> By default end() is called on the destination when the source stream
>   emits end, so that destination is no longer writable.

This allows calls of the form:

```
var http = require('http'),
  fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.createReadStream('path/to/file').pipe(res);
}).listen(3000);
```

If `end` wasn't called on the `response` object, the request would time out.

This would make the request time out:

```
  fs.createReadStream('path/to/file').pipe(res, {end: false});
```